# Typecasting Error in Kotlin: ArrayList

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, casting, kotlin

I am creating a music player app, In which there are a recycler view and many fragments. I am getting an error on my MainScreenFragment.kt file. I checked the error log and the error its shows is:

> ******Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type
>   kotlin.collections.ArrayList /* =
>   java.util.ArrayList */
>   at
>   com.thepanku.musicplayer.Fragments.MainScreenFragment.onCreateView(MainScreenFragment.kt:60)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)******

what would be the reason for the error, any help would be appreciable. I am fed up with the error.

Here is the code:

```
class MainScreenFragment : Fragment() {


var getSongList : ArrayList<Songs>? = null
var nowPlayingBottomBar: RelativeLayout?=null
var playPauseButton: ImageView?=null
var songTitle: TextView?=null
var visibleLayout: RelativeLayout?=null
var noSongs: RelativeLayout?=null
var recyclerView: RecyclerView?= null

var myActivity:Activity?=null

var _mainScreenAdapter : MainScreenAdapter?=null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    activity.title = "All songs"
    visibleLayout = view?.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.visibleLayout)
    noSongs = view?.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.noSongs)
    nowPlayingBottomBar = view?.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.hiddenBarMainScreen)
    songTitle = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.songTitleMainScreen)
    playPauseButton = view?.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.playpauseButton)
    (nowPlayingBottomBar as RelativeLayout).isClickable = false
    recyclerView = view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.contentMain)

    visibleLayout?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    noSongs?.visibility = View.VISIBLE



   //getting error on this line->
   _mainScreenAdapter = MainScreenAdapter(getSongList as ArrayList<Songs>, activity)
    val mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    (recyclerView as RecyclerView).layoutManager = mLayoutManager
    (recyclerView as RecyclerView).itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    (recyclerView as RecyclerView).adapter = _mainScreenAdapter
    return view




}

fun getSongsFromPhone(): ArrayList<Songs>{
    var arrayList = ArrayList<Songs>()
    var contentResolver = myActivity?.contentResolver
    var songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    var songCursor = contentResolver?.query(songUri, null, null, null, null)
    if(songCursor!=null && songCursor.moveToFirst()){
        val songId = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
        val SongTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex((MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE))
        val songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)
        val songData = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)
        val dateIndex = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED)

        while(songCursor.moveToNext()){
            var currentId = songCursor.getLong(songId)
            var currentTitle = songCursor.getString(SongTitle)
            var currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist)
            var currentData = songCursor.getString(songData)
            var currentDate = songCursor.getString(dateIndex)
        }
    }
    return arrayList
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    getSongList = getSongsFromPhone()

}


override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    myActivity = context as Activity
}

override fun onAttach(activity: Activity?) {
    super.onAttach(activity)
    myActivity = activity
}
```

}// Required empty public constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
var getSongList : ArrayList<Songs>? = null
```

and then you say

```
getSongList as ArrayList<Songs>
```

Clearly, `getSongList` is `null`, but you insist on casting it into a not-null type `ArrayList<Song>`. Your hope is that it will be initialized in `onCreateActivity`, but apparently that callback's turn hasn't yet come at the point when your `onCreateView` got called.

I am sorry to hear that you are fed up with this error and hope you'll be able to provide a non-null value for your `getSongList`, for example by calling `getSongsFromPhone()`.